# Can not fetch php json with ReactJs

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

I am trying to fetch php object (as json string) with React. (I am very very new to php)

server.php

```
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000');
........

$product = new Furniture();
$product->set_name('prod1');
$product->set_price('$4');
$product->set_Dimensions('2X2X2');
$myJSON = json_encode($product);


echo $myJSON;
?>
```

myJSON returns following

```
{"name":"prod1","price":"$4","Dimensions":"2X2X2"}
```

React code

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  console.log(data)
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAPI()
  },
    [data == ""])
  async function fetchAPI() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/server.php')
      if (response.ok) {
        let result = await response.json();
        console.log(result)
        setData(result);
      }
      else { return console.log('falied') }
    } catch (error) {
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.name}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

data on console is empty. Also there are no errors in network tab. (for example cors policy) Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does n/w tab XHR request return? Please post the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the working code if modified with axios..

```
import logo from './logo.svg';

import './App.css';

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

import axios from "axios";

function App() {

 const [data, setData] = useState("");

 console.log(data)

 useEffect(() => {

  fetchAPI()

 },

  [data == ""])

 const url = "http://localhost:8000/server.php";

 const fetchAPI = async () => {

  const res = await axios.get(url);

  return setData(res.data);

 };

 return (

  <div className="App">

   {data.name}

  </div>

 );

}

export default App;
```

Comment: I did it. Nothing changed... Console logs empty line again...

Comment: make sure you place above if (responce.ok) line else code will never go there in case responce is not.....  although its react do you have any problem uif we use axios? or u have to stick to the js only.

Comment: sure and dont forget to upvote in casse it works 

Comment: I tried it with axios and it WORKS! Thank you!!!!

Comment: Some explanation of what you have changed and why would improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: @NigelRen i did nothing much as the previous code was writtened in javascript it may have caused some isssue so i suggested to use axios as it is easy to handel and we dont have to manage type conversion and all ...so the questioner tried and it worked .....we must be doing something wrong with the syntex before.